# Perform an action when a process closes

Tags: c#, invalidoperationexception

First of all, I'm programming in Windows Forms Application.
As the title describes, I want to perform an action when a process I started, will close.

I've tried at first:

```
Process s = new Process();  
s.EnableRaisingEvents = true;  
s = Process.Start(processToStart);  
s.Exited += s_Exited;
```

When I do:

```
Process s = new Process();  
s = Process.Start(processToStart);  
s.EnableRaisingEvents = true;  
s.Exited += s_Exited;
```

I get exception of  [System.InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Full exception details:

> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Main' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: Try the `Closing` event of your form.

Comment: Process.WaitForExit()

Comment: You assign a new process to `s` at *`s = Process.Start(processToStart);`*, so you loose *`s.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your original code

**1-** You assign a new process to `s` at *`s = Process.Start(processToStart);`*, so you loose *`s.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`*

**2-** *Exited* event is called from a thread different than you UI thread. Therefore you should use *Invoke* to avoid *cross thread exception*

```
Process p = new Process();
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = processToStart };
p.Exited += (s, e) =>
{
    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        //your code accesing UI, for ex, 
        this.Text = "Exited";
    }));
};
p.Start();
```

***PS:*** Your current code attaches to *Exited* event after the process has started. It may happen (with a low probability), that process exits before you attach to the event. Above code is more correct way of doint it.